# How to map through an object and return a component based on object keys in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, object

I have an objects of object and I want to loop through it and display it based on the key.

Input:

```
export let data = {
  home: {
    title: "home",
    url: "/home"
  },
  dashboard: {
    title: "dashboard",
    url: "/dashboard"
  },
  pages: {
    title: "pages",
    url: "/pages"
  },
  subpages: {
    title: "subpages",
    url: "/pages/subpages"
  },
  login: {
    title: "login",
    url: "/pages/login"
  },
  account: {
    title: "account",
    url: "/dashboard/account"
  }
}
```

if URL is a sub url of other object then it should be displayed below it.

Expected output:

```
Home
dashboard
  account
pages
  subpages
  login
```

It should be displayed like this but in say `<h2>` and `<p>`

Comment: You should have a look at [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

Comment: Are you asking how to extract the data from the object, or are you asking how to display the data in a react component?

Comment: I want to know how to display the data in a react component

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by building up a hierarchy using `reduce`.

```js
let data = {
  home: {
    title: "home",
    url: "/home"
  },
  dashboard: {
    title: "dashboard",
    url: "/dashboard"
  },
  pages: {
    title: "pages",
    url: "/pages"
  },
  subpages: {
    title: "subpages",
    url: "/pages/subpages"
  },
  login: {
    title: "login",
    url: "/pages/login"
  },
  account: {
    title: "account",
    url: "/dashboard/account"
  }
}

var result = Object.entries(data).reduce((acc,[key,{title,url}]) => {
  const parts = url.substring(1).split("/");
  let obj = acc;
  for(var i=0;i<parts.length;i++){
    if(!obj[parts[i]]) obj[parts[i]] = {}
    obj = obj[parts[i]];
  }
  obj.url = url;
  return acc;
},{});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -2):

Hey this code snipped can help

```js
let data = {
  home: {
    title: "home",
    url: "/home"
  },
  dashboard: {
    title: "dashboard",
    url: "/dashboard"
  },
  pages: {
    title: "pages",
    url: "/pages"
  },
  subpages: {
    title: "subpages",
    url: "/pages/subpages"
  },
  login: {
    title: "login",
    url: "/pages/login"
  },
  account: {
    title: "account",
    url: "/dashboard/account"
  }
}

Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => {
  console.log(key);
})
```

Comment: subpages, login and account should be displayed under their respective parent titles